# How can I define a struct in x64/x32Dbg?

Tags: struct, x64dbg

See the image how there is ecx, ecx+4, ecx+8, ecx+24, etc... What if this is a struct and I want to define it... Can I do this in x64Dbg and if so, how? I do see a Struct tab in the hex dump area, but if I right-click, there is no option to define a struct.[image]

Comment: What do you mean to define a struct ? you mean a C/C++ struct ? I see it stowed in Data Segment.

Comment: Yes a c style struct. Are you familiar with IDA Pro how you can press a key and define a c style struct and then apply it to offsets like that so that they are properly labeled

Answer (score 3):

Right now it is not possible to label instructions in the disassembly as structure members. It is however possible to define structs and visit them in memory (similar to 010 editor). The main sources of information about this are [here](https://x64dbg.com/blog/2016/12/04/type-system.html) and [here](https://x64dbg.com/blog/2016/11/27/weekly-digest-14.html#types).

As an example if you have the following code:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
    bool b;
    const char* c;
};

void test(MyStruct* p)
{
    MyStruct* s = p;
    s->a = 0x1234;
    s->b = true;
    s->c = "Hello world";
}

int main()
{
    MyStruct s;
    test(&s);
    return s.a;
}
```

You use the `Parse header` option in the `Struct` tab to parse the following header:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
    bool b;
    const char* c;
};
```

This will load the structure (use the command `EnumTypes` to see a list of types). Now when you're paused at the disassembly of the `test` function you can use the `Visit type` option from the `Struct` tab to show the contents of the memory at `ecx` in a structural way:

[image]

The addresses of the structure members will also be added as temporary labels so you can see what an instruction refers to in the info box:

[image]

This feature has not been further developed because there was a lack of interest from the community.

Comment: Excellent work again. Thanks for making this the go to Windows debugger.